# Losing internet connection, but not signal! (wifi)

Tags: networking, crash

I am having an issue with internet connection. My laptop and about 10 other devices (pc, laptop, smart phone) are connected to wireless router, via wifi signal. Today, I tried to log to router via default gateway, to see connections. It worked, but, from that moment, I am having issues with network. Actually, my laptop has great wifi signal, but network crashes. It works about minute or two, crashes, and works again. I never had this issue, and also none of devices using the same network as I do have this issue now, so I am pretty sure that it is something wrong with my laptop.

I tried restarting laptop and router, restarting network settings ("netsh winsock reset" command in cmd),turning off windows firewall but nothing seems to work... 
I am using windows 8.1 and laptop Lenovo g505.

Anyone has any idea what might it be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like your router cant handle that many connections and is dropping them when its overloaded.

What type of router do you have?

Low end routers can only handle up to so many connections at once.

Comment: I have pirelli dsl router... Maybe it is the reason, but it has been working like this, I don't think that there were less connections before...

Comment: Looks like it is all solved now, but I still don't know what the problem was...